# How to submit jobs to spark using yarn rest api? I want to use YARN REST API for submitting job to spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am building an interface for triggering spark-jobs and checking job status.

I cannot use 3rd party libraries like Livy, spark job server. I want to make APIs for starting and submitting jobs to spark cluster via REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spark jobserver - https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Update -

I didn't see the spark job server cannot be used, you can use the below

## Job Submission

```
curl -X POST http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
  "appArgs" : [ "myAppArgument1" ],
  "appResource" : "file:/myfilepath/spark-job-1.0.jar",
  "clientSparkVersion" : "1.5.0",
  "environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
  },
  "mainClass" : "com.mycompany.MyJob",
  "sparkProperties" : {
    "spark.jars" : "file:/myfilepath/spark-job-1.0.jar",
    "spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
    "spark.app.name" : "MyJob",
    "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
    "spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
    "spark.master" : "spark://spark-cluster-ip:6066"
  }
}
```

## Job Status

```
curl http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20151008145126-0000
```

Comment: The question explicitly says that cannot be used

Comment: @cricket_007 - I didn't see that, I have updated my answer

Comment: Isn't this for standalone master? The question asked about YARN

Comment: No, it is for a cluster with on which only spark is installed.